# How to filter is_active product by Backward relationship in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="product/")
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    discount = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

template

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {% for product in categories.product_set.all %}
        <h1> {{ product.name }} </h1>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to show filter products(Those are is_active) that belong to a category in Django template.

Comment: So you want to filter product in descending order with ``is_active`` set to True

Comment: Please share the relevant view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the category and name of active products then:

```
{% for product in product.objects.all %}
   {% if product.is_active %}
   <h1> {{ product.category }} </h1>
   <h1> {{ product.name }} </h1>
   {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
```